# Function format number

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, formatting

For oracle,

Can anyone fixes the function below to let it works with "a number (10,2)"? Just this condition only.

Here I come with the function..

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fmt_num(N1 in NUMBER)
RETURN CHAR
IS
BEGIN
RETURN TO_CHAR(N1,'FM9,9999.99');
END;
/
```

And I can use this with the SQL statement as follow

```
SELECT Fmt_num(price) from A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "works" and what output you want.  My guess is that you just want to update the format mask

```
to_char( n1, 'fm999,999,999.99' )
```

That assumes, though, that you want to use hard-coded decimal points and separators and that you want to use the American/ European convention of separating numbers in sets of 3 rather than, say, the traditional Indian system of representing large numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I want to create a conditions for a specific column such as
the column which has number(3,2) can't use this function.

Comment: @NiickMosqow - Why can't you use this function with a smaller number?  If you pass in a 4 digit number, for example, the output will be precisely identical to the output of your current function.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Fmt_num(N1 in NUMBER)
RETURN CHAR
IS
BEGIN
RETURN TO_CHAR(N1,'FM99,999,999.99');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the comma every 4 digits, you could do this:

```
TO_CHAR(N1,'FM9999,9999,9999.99');
```

However, I'd recommend you use the locale-safe version (G for the grouping character, D for the decimal separator):

```
TO_CHAR(N1,'FM9999G9999G9999D99');
```